# How to delete messages properly?

Tags: android, mongodb, message

I'm a beginner in android so please do excuse me if my question seem to be foolish.Basically I've developed an one-one messaging app using `socket.io` and `mongodb` and it's working fine . It's saving a unique room key for two users in db which is accessed by them by their email id when they login to my app .

My message storing format:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5abcf523f388e02978bf7780"),
"_mid" : "roman-reigns+john-cena",
"from" : "roman.reigns",
"to" : "john.cena",
"msg_time" : "29 Mar 2018(07-41-29)",
"msg" : "hy"
```

}

These things are working without any problem.
I've designed the single message delete as **unsend** so that it would remove the sender's message and this idea seems to be fine. But now what I'm asking is how can I give total delete option to the users . I meant in my case these chat conversation will be shown in both the user's phone so when one user will try to delete all messages what would happen if I'll delete all the messages from the db at that point then the `message list` will also be deleted from other user and it won't be `user friendly`.So how can I design **all delete** message format so that it won't be deleted from the other person's list but be deleted from the current deleter's phone.

*Please do suggest any ideas so that my problem would be solved.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one more params as flag where

deleteMsg flag where 4 values can put

0 for active
1 for sender deleted
2 for receiver deleted
3 for both

If it's complex then

keep two flag

senderDeleted = 0 active 1 deleted
receiverDeleted = 0 active 1 deleted

Comment: Thanks a lot sir . Wow just amazing it's so simple I had never thought in this way